# Operator error.

Tags: java, arrays

I have this error:The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) `double[], int`. for the last line of code in this method.

```
private void average(double array[][],int column,int row)
{
    double array2[]=new double[row];
     int count1,count2;
     for(count1=0;count1<row;count1++)
     {
         float total=0;
         for(count2=0;count2<column;count2++)
         {
             array2[count1]+=array[count1][count2];
         }
         array[count1]= array[count1]/column;
     }
}
```

what might be wrong?

Comment: By the way, don't name your variables things like `array` and `array2`. It makes it difficult to understand what's supposed to be going on. And what is the purpose of passing in `row` and `column`? Unless they're some sort of bound within the matrix (in which case, more descriptive names), use `array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to calculate the average in the 1D array :

```
array2[count1]= array2[count1]/column;
```

`array[count1]` is an array, so you can't apply numeric operators on it.

Answer (score 0):

You try to divide array[count1], which is array itself as array is two dimensioned array.
Here:

```
array[count1]= array[count1]/column
```